# Notepad++ Can I dock the find window?

Tags: notepad++

Can I dock the "find window" popup in notepad++? I work with multiple screens and when I do a Ctrl F the find popup could be anywhere on 3 screens. I'd like to have it docked inside the main notepad++ screen, but I can't find the option anywhere.

Not talking about the search results, but the find window where you enter what you're looking for.

Comment: You can't. +1 because it would be pretty cool if you could. However the Find window always shows up in the exact same spot you closed it at. So if you just remember to always leave it in one monitor at one position then it will always open there.

Comment: That's what I found out. Though I'm always moving things around depending on the type of project I'm working on at the moment. Oh well, just another minor annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ (I have version v8.1.3) allowed you to use "Incremental Search" (Ctrl-Alt-I). This is a very basic searching tool and it opens at the bottom to the current window.

Answer (score 1):

Double click the title bar of the search results window and it should return to its default docked position

Comment: This does indeed dock the search results window, but it looks like the question author wants to dock the find window (the one with the search options). Could you please adjust your answer to address that?

Comment: This reply was a lifesaver.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Yes**, you can dock. But not the find window you usually use.

I just interchanged the `Find` and `Incremental search` keyboard shortcuts. Now I am able to do search easily with keyboard.

- Do `ctrl + F`
- provide search string
- press `Enter` for incremental search.

Easy!!

`Settings` -> `Shortcut mapper` -> click on `Find @ 101` -> click on `Modify` button -> Provide any key (I provided same as 110 which is Ctrl + Alt + I)
A `red` colored error will be shown as conflict. Never mind, just provide the `CTRL + F` for incremental search. All set!